# Исходный код MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно найти исходный код MFC. Если конкретней, то я бы хотел посмотреть реализацию класса CFile, но не смог найти в интернете.

Comment: так и правильно что не нашли, MFC же не open source

Comment: А исходный код похожей библиотеки можно найти?

Comment: чем определяется схожесть ? например класс для работы с файлами есть и в STL

Comment: Ну я хочу посмотреть, как более умные и опытные программисты реализовали класс для работы с файлами. Мне посоветовали в исходники MFC посмотреть, но никак найти не могу.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/file.cs — исходники класса `File` из дотнета (C#).

Comment: а именно на c++ нет?

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem посмотрите тут

Comment: @ampawd, а вот [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/using-the-mfc-source-files?view=vs-2019) говорится, что исходный код предоставляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошу прощения за столь краткий ответ: посмотрите [здесь](https://github.com/pixelspark/corespark/tree/master/Libraries/atlmfc/src/mfc).

Comment: Кратко, зато информативно. Спасибо за помощь. Жалко я когда посмотрел я так ничего и не понял)

Comment: @ПавелЕриков, рад помочь! Быстро Вы посмотрели :)